# Display points on google maps in web browser using spring java

Tags: java, spring, google-maps, google-api

I have set of longitudes and latitude in array , I want to display them on google maps  in a web browser using  google API , spring and java

Answer (score 3):

as far as my knowledge, spring is a backend RESTful web service, and I think what you want to do is to dynamically build the javascript that display multiple markers on the Google Maps.

You can look at [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple), or the [javascript market documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to first convert the array into a JSON array, that would be easy for your Java/Spring code to parse and then finally display on the Google Maps using the Maps Library.

To convert array into JSON:

```
String mStringArray[] = { "String1", "String2" };

JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(mStringArray));
```

To display the latitude/longitude that are now in JSON on Google Maps follow this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-find-location-using-ip-address-jquery-google-map/).

Hope this Helps!!